# Basic Python Messagebox size change

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I change the size of the window that this message-box appears in? I built the box myself to allow me to change the option to "Thanks".

Here is my code so far:

```
def messageWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    win.title('warning')
    message = "This will delete stuff"
    Label(win, text=message).pack()
    Button(win, text='Thanks!', command=win.destroy).pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`geometry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method to set the dimensions of your window.

Example:

```
win.geometry("500x500")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, new it was simple, almost embarrassed!